# Pass value from one parent component to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one component Avanger and when the component unmounts i want to transfer its state to the other component named Battle
I try to pass the values of the Avanger state to Battle every time when Avanger is updating so am trying this

```
  componentDidUpdate() {
        console.log(this.state.selectedAvangers)
        return <div><Battle val={this.state.selectedAvangers} /></div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep the state in a parent container (higher order component) and pass the state into these components as props. It sounds like the components that share the same state should be built as presentational stateless components.

Other solutions that don't include prop drilling:

Redux
Context API